# NodeJS assigning variables not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I must be missing something here. I cannot get the variable to override properly. When I console log the data, there is a returned json object. I think I am not creating and or assigning the data object to the variable. If I console log the tcResponse I get undefined.

```
router.get('/testcase/:id', function(req, res) {
    var tcResponse;
    var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
    var options_auth={
        user:"username",
        password:"password"
    };

    client = new Client(options_auth);

    args ={
        data:{test:"hello"}, // data passed to REST method (only useful in POST, PUT or PATCH methods)
        path:{
            "baseUrl":"http://local.dev/flex/services/rest/latest",
            "id":req.params.id
        }, // path substitution var
        parameters:{arg1:"hello",arg2:"world"}, // query parameter substitution vars
        headers:{"test-header":"client-api"} // request headers
    };

    client.get("${baseUrl}/testcase/${id}", args, function(data, response){
        // parsed response body as js object
        console.log(data);
        tcResponse = data;
        // raw response
        //console.log(response);
    });

    res.render('testcase', { 
        title: 'Zephyr Report - Test Case',
        testCaseId: req.params.id,
        tcResponseJson: tcResponse
    });
});
```

I believe I am missing something but unsure what. Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to log `tcResponse`? What is this code supposed to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: This is pulling in a 3rd party REST API. I just want to push the return json object to the view.

Comment: I think the problem is that I am setting the tcReposonse = data inside a function(client.get) that is not returning anything

Comment: Yes, see my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, you're trying to call a REST API and then return the resulting data?

In which case, the problem is you're not waiting for your asynchronous `get` to callback before calling `render`. You need to move the code that uses the async response into the callback for the async function.

```
client.get("${baseUrl}/testcase/${id}", args, function(data, response) {
    res.render('testcase', { 
        title: 'Zephyr Report - Test Case',
        testCaseId: req.params.id,
        tcResponseJson: data
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting the data. I'm just trying put it in a variable that I can send to the view later

Comment: You weren't sending it to the view *later*. You were sending `undefined` to the view before you'd received the data, because the receipt of the data is an asynchronous process.

Comment: ok, so in my jade template pre #{tcResponseJson} and what the webpage shows is [object Object]. So my guess is that is my json object

Comment: Yes, that is what you get if you convert a plain object to a string. If you want a JSON string you need `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Comment: Well I would not want it as a string I would want it as a JSON object so I can get data from it to build my table in the view

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object" in this context. You either have an object, or a JSON string representing that object.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(data);
tcResponse = data
// raw response
//console.log(response);
```

The problem is that you log response, which is indeed not defined. Try to log tcResponse instead.

```
console.log(tcResponse);
```